# Parsing IMDB with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, imdb

I've stripped the following code from IMDB's mobile site using BeautifulSoup, with Python 2.7.

I want to create a separate object for the episode number '1', title 'Winter is Coming', and IMDB score '8.9'. Can't seem to figure out how to split apart the episode number and the title.

```
   <a class="btn-full" href="/title/tt1480055?ref_=m_ttep_ep_ep1">
     <span class="text-large">
      1.
      <strong>
       Winter Is Coming
      </strong>
     </span>
     <br/>
     <span class="mobile-sprite tiny-star">
     </span>
     <strong>
      8.9
     </strong>
     17 Apr. 2011
    </a>
```

Comment: I went to answer your question, but then realized I sort of misunderstood.  You can grab the title (if all episodes are set up like this) by doing something like `soup.select('span > strong')`, but that still leaves you needing to grab the episode number.

Comment: "Winter Is Coming..." And... Cue Game of Thrones puns :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` to locate the `span` with the class `text-large` to the specific element you need.

Once you have your desired `span`, you can use `next` to grab the next line, containing the episode number and `find` to locate the `strong` containing the title

```
html = """
<a class="btn-full" href="/title/tt1480055?ref_=m_ttep_ep_ep1">
     <span class="text-large">
      1.
      <strong>
       Winter Is Coming
      </strong>
     </span>
     <br/>
     <span class="mobile-sprite tiny-star">
     </span>
     <strong>
      8.9
     </strong>
     17 Apr. 2011
    </a>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
span = soup.find('span', attrs={'text-large'})
ep = str(span.next).strip()
title = str(span.find('strong').text).strip()

print ep
print title

> 1. 
> Winter Is Coming
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have each `a class="btn-full"`, you can use the span classes to get the tags you want, the strong tag is a child of the span with the  `text-large` class so you just need to call `.strong.text` on the Tag, for the span with the css class `mobile-sprite tiny-star`, you need to find the next strong tag as it is a sibling of the span not a child:

```
h = """<a class="btn-full" href="/title/tt1480055?ref_=m_ttep_ep_ep1">
     <span class="text-large">
      1.
      <strong>
       Winter Is Coming
      </strong>
     </span>
     <br/>
     <span class="mobile-sprite tiny-star">
     </span>
     <strong>
      8.9
     </strong>
     17 Apr. 2011
    </a>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
title = soup.select_one("span.text-large").strong.text.strip()
score = soup.select_one("span.mobile-sprite.tiny-star").find_next("strong").text.strip()

print(title, score)
```

Which gives you:

```
(u'Winter Is Coming', u'8.9')
```

If you really want to get the episode the simplest way is to split the text once:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
ep, title = soup.select_one("span.text-large").text.split(None, 1)
score = soup.select_one("span.mobile-sprite.tiny-star").find_next("strong").text.strip()

print(ep, title.strip(), score)
```

Which will give you:

```
(u'1.', u'Winter Is Coming', u'8.9')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using url html scraping with reguest and regular expression search.

```
import os, sys, requests

frame = ('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1480055?ref_=m_ttep_ep_ep1')
f = requests.get(frame)
helpme = f.text
import re
result = re.findall('itemprop="name" class="">(.*?)&nbsp;', helpme)
result2 = re.findall('"ratingCount">(.*?)</span>', helpme)
result3 = re.findall('"ratingValue">(.*?)</span>', helpme)
print result[0].encode('utf-8')
print result2[0]
print result3[0]
```

output:

```
Winter Is Coming
24,474
9.0
```